# "Hijack" system-wide http links on OSX and ideally iOS and open native App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos

Assume I build a native Facebook App for the Mac or for iOS (just an example).

Now whenever the user opens an url `http://facebook.com/..` I want my app to open rather than the browser. This is similar to opening google maps links prior to iOS 6 on iOS.

Unfortunately (like in the case with facebook) I do not own the service but I am only consuming its API so I can't forward to another URL from the actual website.

My question now is whether this is possible:

1. On the Mac with my native Mac App
2. On iOS (However, here I would be quite supprised if this was possible)

Comment: For desktop, I'm pretty sure you would need to use a browser add-on in the browsers you want to do this for. For iOS, I'm pretty sure this is impossible, since browsers add-on's for iOS are limited.

Comment: for OSX have a look on GlimmerBlocker or Charles Proxy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS you can register a custom protocol which triggers if any other app (system, or not) tries to open that URL.

So in other words. Say your app registers the protocol 'myprotocol'. Then if you go to safari and type in the addressbar: myprotocol://sometext it will open your app, and your app can handle that URL.

This ALSO works from HTML loaded externally from Safari. So if your website is shown and on your website you link to myprotocol://sometext and someone clicks the link, then again your app will be opened.

Catching generic http requests system wide is unsupported on iOS

Answer (score 0):

search for CustomURL / customProtocol for IOS apps.  you will get your required answers. do let me know if you need a sample code.